# where to include google analytics tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

I want to use google analytics in my website, but I don't understand where I have to put the tracking code. I built my web page using Yii and php, and I am also using templates. I read the google page about the tracking code, and it says:

> If your website uses templates to generate pages, enter it just before
>   the closing tag in the file that contains the the  section.

I tried to put the tracking code before `</head>`, but it didn't work. Please, someone could help me? I don't understand what google means.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be placing it within your views, preferably before the `</head>` tag. When you say it didn't work, what is it doing? Did it throw an error - if so, what?

Comment: Also, I created Yii extensions to help with installing [ga.js](https://github.com/TagPlanet/yii-analytics-ga) and [analytics.js](https://github.com/TagPlanet/yii-analytics-ua). They might be of use to you.

Comment: MisterPhilip I put the script code exactly before ´</head>´, but the google analytic page say Status: track not installed. Even so, I can see that my page recive visits.

Comment: Well, I think that the problem was that I had to wait more in order to google activate the tracking code.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that could be. Usually the data shows up pretty quickly, but sometimes you have a delay (up to 24hours). Also make sure you set the date to today / yesterday's date in the reports!